# Widget en google sites

Tags: html, css, web, google-sites

tengo una duda, estoy insertando un Widget de comentarios de Google en una pagina web hecha en Google Sites pero al momento de visualizarlo en móvil se muestran casi ocultos y con barra de desplazamiento, consejos?

[image: Imagen de Referencia]

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El único consejo que te voy a dar es que leas la información en los enlaces que te he dado. Aquí no damos consejos ni opiniones personales. Las preguntas deben ser específicas, reproducibles, en donde expongas con claridad un problema, los pasos que haz dado para intentar resolverlo, el resultado obtenido y el resultado esperado. Si crees que puedes [edit] tu pregunta y enfocarla de esa manera, seguramente será bienvenida, de lo contrario podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.